# dynamically populating number fields with radio button onclick and javascript function?

Tags: javascript, php, gravity-forms-plugin

I have three things: 1. Two Number fields (from standard class), which i wanted to populate dynamically. 2. one Javascript function to extract coordinate using geolocator; 3. a radio button, when clicked the number fields will be populated dynamically

Following is the code i am using to do the task, but its not working. could you please help me out? what wrong i am doing? thank you in advance for your help

** i have checked my geolocator function is working correctly. i guess, my problem is in the code, which extracting the code and populate the number fields dynamically.

```
add_filter('gform_field_value_longitude', 'populate_longitude');
function populate_longitude($value){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var x=document.getElementById("latitude");
        var y=document.getElementById("longitude");

    if(navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation, errorHandler, {enableHighAccuracy:false, maximumAge:60000, timeout:27000});
    }else{
        alert('Votre navigateur ne prend malheureusement pas en charge la géolocalisation.');
        }
    });

    function showLocation(position){
        x.value=position.coords.latitude;  
        y.value=position.coords.longitude;
    }

    <input type="radio" value="extract_coordinate" onclick="populate_longitude;">

    </script>
<?php
    return "$y";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that code working? As in when you open the page in browser, does it show all the fields required? I don't know about the plugin you're using, but it appears the code might have syntax errors.

The first thing that drew my attention though is that in the onclick event, you're not actually calling the function. Try this:

```
<input type="radio" value="extract_coordinate" onclick="populate_longitude();">
```

Comment: Hello there. the code, i have provided above, i had put this exact code in function.php page in wordpress. yes, the code is working. i am trying to make use of html5 geolocation function, found in w3 school site.and yes the page is showing all the field requires, here is the page link, where you can find the gravity form: http://www.pointorb.com/registration/ . ABout the syntax errors, Sorry, that was my mistake. i have corrected it but still its not working. any clue? please let me know if you requires some more info about that. Thank you

Comment: I got it to work on my side but with a few changes in the source code from the page you linked. 1) The <body> & first radio <input> tags should be outside the ending </script> tag (Lines 133-135). 2) In function 'updateFields', "document.getElementById("mylon").value" points to a non-existent ID so no actual field is being updated. 3) Function 'locationError' that's passed in 'getCurrentPosition' doesn't exist. 4) The radio button that is actually displayed doesn't do anything onclick. 4) Having all the functions in a document.ready block defeats the purpose of having a radio button to click.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have any progress with this? If you need the code in the OP to be fixed as opposed to the one in the link you provided, check the below. Your function should be inside the <*script> tag since you need to call it from the onclick event so it should be Javascript. You also need to remove document.ready and just use regular functions instead.

```
//add_filter('gform_field_value_longitude', 'populate_longitude');
<script type="text/javascript">
    function populate_longitude(){
        var x=document.getElementById("latitude");
        var y=document.getElementById("longitude");

        if(navigator.geolocation){
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation);
        }else{
           alert('Votre navigateur ne prend malheureusement pas en charge la géolocalisation.');
        }
     }

     function showLocation(position){
         document.getElementById("latitude").value = position.coords.latitude;
         document.getElementById("longitude").value =position.coords.longitude;
     }
</script>

<input type="radio" value="extract_coordinate" onclick="populate_longitude();">
<input type="text" value="" id="latitude">
<input type="text" value="" id="longitude">
```